# Minecraft plugin config.yml sections doesn't save

Tags: java, plugins, server, minecraft

I am writing a Minecraft plugin based on spigot coding.
But there I have the following issue, I am trying to edit a configuration file through the plugin, but when I attempt to store the information the data is not stored. As an example when I change `name` from `Archive` to `Archive Stats` and reload the server. Then the configuration `name` returns to `Archive`.

```
Archive:
  Material:
    ==: org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack
    v: 2586
    type: BOOKSHELF
  ArchiveAtStart: false
  Name: Archive
```

when I change the name to "Archive Stats"

```
Archive:
  Material:
    ==: org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack
    v: 2586
    type: BOOKSHELF
  ArchiveAtStart: false
  Name: Archive Stats
```

and reloaded the server, it still changes back to "Archive"

```
Archive:
  Material:
    ==: org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack
    v: 2586
    type: BOOKSHELF
  ArchiveAtStart: false
  Name: Archive
```

so here are the 2 codes to show:

1. The class

```
package com.Fender.Bedrock.files;

import com.Fender.Bedrock.Bedrock;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.configuration.InvalidConfigurationException;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.YamlConfiguration;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CustomConfig
{

    private static Bedrock plugin;
    public static File file;
    private static FileConfiguration customFile;

    public static void setup(Bedrock plugin1)
    {

        plugin = plugin1;

        file = new File(plugin.getDataFolder(), "config.yml");


        if(!file.exists())
        {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            }catch (IOException e){

            }
        }

        customFile = new YamlConfiguration();
        save();


        try{customFile.load(file);}
        catch (IOException | InvalidConfigurationException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static FileConfiguration get()
    {

        return customFile;
    }


    public static void save()
    {
        try
        {
            customFile.save(file);
        }catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.print("Couldn't save file!");
        }
    }

    public static void load()
    {
        try
        {
            try {
                try {
                    customFile.load(file);
                }catch (InvalidConfigurationException i){
                    System.out.print("Couldn't load file!");
                }
            }catch (FileNotFoundException f)
            {
                System.out.print("Couldn't load file!");
            }
        }catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.print("Couldn't load file!");
        }
    }

    public static void reload()
    {
        customFile = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(file);
    }

    public boolean exists()
    {
        if(file.exists()){
            return true;
        }else
            {
                return false;
            }
    }
}
```

2. The method for the main class

```
public void FileCreate()
    {
        CustomConfig.setup(this);
        CustomConfig.reload();
        {
            CustomConfig.get().addDefault("Name1", "§dHis");
            CustomConfig.get().addDefault("Place", 1);

            CustomConfig.get().createSection("Archive");
            CustomConfig.get().getConfigurationSection("Archive").addDefault("Material", itemStack);
            CustomConfig.get().getConfigurationSection("Archive").addDefault("ArchiveAtStart", false);
            CustomConfig.get().getConfigurationSection("Archive").addDefault("Name", "Archive");

            CustomConfig.get().createSection("noob").addDefault("help", false);
        }
        CustomConfig.get().options().copyHeader(true);
        CustomConfig.get().options().copyDefaults(true);
        CustomConfig.save();
        //saveResource("config.yml", false);
        this.saveDefaultConfig();
    }
```

Finally, this is my plugin main method :

```
@Override
public void onEnable() {
     FileCreate();
     this.getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
     this.saveConfig();
}
```

Comment: Are you saving the config on plugin shutdown (i.e. from the config stored in memory)? That may be overriding your changes on restart. Also there's a easier way to get the main config (config.yml) which will also handle loading default, using `JavaPlugin.#getConfig()`, i.e. `plugin.getConfig()` in your case.

Comment: Ok so your first question, does this have anything to do with the issue? ```@Override
    public void onEnable()
    {

        FileCreate();

        
        this.getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
        this.saveConfig();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable()
    {
        getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "[" + 
        getName() + "] " + ChatColor.RED + "Plugin is disabled");
    }```this is the on enable and on disable methods

Comment: Ah, no that looks fine. I'd add that to the question details though for future readers. Might be worth reposting on bukkit/spigot forums as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue appear because you can overriding lines at startup. More exactly, when adding default lines.

This will just add a default value, but not overriding:

```
CustomConfig.get().addDefault("Name1", "§dHis");
```

It's this that change everything:

```
CustomConfig.get().createSection("Archive");
```

You should keep using `addDefault()`. For section just use `addDefault("mysection.key", "myval")`, and so, in your case:

```
CustomConfig.get().addDefault("Archive.Name", "Archive");
```

Comment: Yes I'm late, but it's never too old ! :)